# android.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, batch-file, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have setup up the environment for cocos2d-x. I have edited the create-android-project.bat file according to my Cygwin, SDK and NDK locations. Now when I try to create a new cocos2d-x project double clicking on the create-android-project.bat file, I get errors. Please help. I am in a mess.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a double `\\`.

Please refer to: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android